# spring boot `jdbcTemplate.query` RowMapper generic issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, java-17

I have stuck in RowMapper, the code is showing Generic type error.

```
@Override
    public List<Person> selectAllPerson() {
        final String sql = "SELECT id, name FROM person";
        List<Person> persons = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new PersonRowMapper(), new Object[]{});
                                                       //^^^^^type error^^^^
        return persons;
    }
```

netbeans IDE is also showing error hits. but i am unable to understand
[image]

And here is `RowMapper` Class
package com.gmc.dpro.dao;

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.gmc.dpro.model.Person;
import java.util.UUID;

public class PersonRowMapper implements RowMapper<Person>{
    
    @Override
    public Person mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return new Person(UUID.fromString(rs.getString("id")), rs.getString("name"));
    }
}
```

the code is throwing following type error

> required:
> java.lang.String,org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.RowMapper,java.lang.Object[]
> found:
> java.lang.String,com.gmc.dpro.dao.PersonRowMapper,java.lang.Object[]
> reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
> (argument mismatch; com.gmc.dpro.dao.PersonRowMapper cannot be converted to org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.RowMapper)

i am beginner in Java spring boot, can you please provide solution for above error.

Comment: You probably using wrong jdbcTemplate?
as you error said `org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.RowMapper`

Comment: @samabcde correct, i just replaced `org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcTemplate` from `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` it worked thanks